Is defining extern as a macro undefined behaviour?
I came across some code that
defines some functions using a macro named SMTP_LINKAGE that expands to extern.
snippets of interest
#ifdef SMTP_TEST
# define SMTP_LINKAGE extern
# include "../test/seams.h"
#else 
# define SMTP_LINKAGE static                               
#endif

SMTP_LINKAGE  enum str_getdelim_retcode
smtp_str_getdelimfd(struct str_getdelimfd *const gdf){
  ..
}

The smtp_str_getdelimfd function's prototype is defined in another file as
int
smtp_str_getdelimfd(struct str_getdelimfd *const gdf);

note the return value is int
If the macro is removed and the extern keyword is used directly the compiler complains of the defintion mismatch.
If however the SMTP_LINKAGE macro is used as shown, no such error occurs.
What causes this behaviour?
Is it specified somewhere ?
I can not find any information on this topic.
Errors for the various possibilities
with enum
no previous prototype for 'smtp_str_getdelimfd' [-Werror=missing-prototypes]
with static
static declaration of 'smtp_str_getdelimfd' follows non-static declaration
with SMTP_LINKAGE
ok
EDIT !
turns out I had suppresed a warning on earlier tests and without doing so the compiler catches the return type mismatch when using SMTP_LINKAGE
with SMTP_LINKAGE conflicting types for 'smtp_str_getdelimfd' due to enum/integer mismatch; have 'enum str_getdelim_retcode(struct str_getdelimfd * const)' [-Wenum-int-mismatch]
So no issues defining a macro as extern.

What exactly was the code you were trying to compile, after removing the macro?  What exactly was the compiler error message?  It sounds like you removed more than just the macro, leaving the function with no return type declaration, but you haven't provided enough details for us to do more than guess.

@jasonharper https://github.com/somnisoft/smtp-client

@jasonharper I added the error messages to the question

Turns out it's not undefined and using the macro should produce the same results as using the extern keyword directly. See my answer.

@jasonharper Indeed turns out you were right. I had supressed the warning in earlier tests. Removing the -Wno-error=enum-int-mismatch brought the warning back.  So the compiler is in fact behaving as it should.

Macros quite literally are used as text substitution, so just as if you typed it manually, if this would work, there should be no issue with defining a macro for it.
By this logic, if it doesn't work when defining as extern but works as this macro, it suggest the macro is not setting it to extern, rather to static.
This could potentially be due to the test failing due to unforeseen linking issues.

Good point but alas I tried and static gives a different error. I added the error messages for both to the question

According to gcc
You may define any valid identifier as a macro, even if it is a C keyword
source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_3.html#:~:text=You%20may%20define%20any%20valid,it%20is%20a%20C%20keyword
So it's not undefined behaviour
and the same error as with using enum should occur when using SMTP_LINKAGE
EDIT
turns out I had suppresed a warning on earlier tests and without doing so the compiler catches the return type mismatch when using SMTP_LINKAGE
